# Странное поведение функции any

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
hits = [
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
]

print(any(hits))
```

Почему возвращает результат `True`?

Comment: `bool([False, False, False])` -> `True`. Закреплено в стандарте: "любой непустой список приводится к `True`, любой пустой к `False`. Ваш код буквально означает "напечатай истину если хотя бы один из элементов-списков не пуст".

Comment: `print(any([item for elem in hits for item in elem]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `any` не просматривает значения во вложенных списках. Python любой непустой список интерпретирует как `True`, поэтому и результатом является `True`. Если вы хотите просмотреть все значения, то это можно сделать так:

```
print(any(map(any, hits)))
```

Comment: Или `print(any(map(any, hits)))`.